# why is my marching cubes algorithm so slow?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, optimization

i have somewhat implemented marching cubes in unity/c# (you dont need to know unity to help me though) and i cant stop feeling like i have made a big mistake in my code because it is so slow. i am already running it on a separate thread but it just takes ages to complete. please help me optimize my code.

```
private void _UpdateChunk()
{
    lock (this)
    {
        // clear the tri, vert and uv lists
        ClearMeshData();

        // Loop through each "cube" in the terrain.
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < width; z++)
                {

                    // Create an array of floats representing each corner of a cube and get the value from our terrainMap.
                    float[] cube = new float[8];
                    float[] strengths = new float[8];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                    {

                        Vector3Int corner = new Vector3Int(x, y, z) + gamedata.CornerTable[i];
                        cube[i] = terrainMap[corner.x, corner.y, corner.z].BlockType;
                        strengths[i] = terrainMap[corner.x, corner.y, corner.z].Strength;

                    }

                    // Pass the value into the MarchCube function.
                    MarchCube(new Vector3(x, y, z), cube, strengths);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void MarchCube(Vector3 position, float[] cube, float[] strengths)
{

    // Get the configuration index of this cube.
    int configIndex = GetCubeConfiguration(cube);

    // If the configuration of this cube is 0 or 255 (completely inside the terrain or completely outside of it) we don't need to do anything.
    if (configIndex == 0 || configIndex == 255)
        return;

    // Loop through the triangles. There are never more than 5 triangles to a cube and only three vertices to a triangle.
    int edgeIndex = 0;
    Vector3 vert1 = new Vector3();
    Vector3 vert2 = new Vector3();
    float vert1sample = 0;
    float vert2sample = 0;
    float lerp = 0;
    int indice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++)
        {
                
            // Get the current indice. We increment triangleIndex through each loop.
            indice = gamedata.TriangleTable[configIndex, edgeIndex];

            // If the current edgeIndex is -1, there are no more indices and we can exit the function.
            if (indice == -1)
                return;
            // Get the vertices for the start and end of this edge.
            vert1 = position + gamedata.EdgeTable[indice, 0];
            vert2 = position + gamedata.EdgeTable[indice, 1];
            vert1sample = strengths[gamedata.EdgeIndexTable[indice, 0]];
            vert2sample = strengths[gamedata.EdgeIndexTable[indice, 1]];
                
            // Get the midpoint of this edge.
            lerp = Mathf.Abs(vert1sample) / (Mathf.Abs(vert2sample) + Mathf.Abs(vert1sample));

                

            Vector3 vertPosition = Vector3.Lerp(vert1, vert2, lerp);
            
                
            // Add to our vertices and triangles list and incremement the edgeIndex.

            vertices.Add(vertPosition);

            triangles.Add(vertices.Count - 1);
            if (getChunkVoxel(vert1 + chunkPosition) != 0)
            {
                uvs.Add(new Vector2(getChunkVoxel(vert1 + chunkPosition) - 1, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                uvs.Add(new Vector2(getChunkVoxel(vert2 + chunkPosition) - 1, getChunkVoxel(vert2 + chunkPosition) - 1));
            }
                
                
                
                edgeIndex++;
        }
    }
}
int GetCubeConfiguration(float[] cube)
{

    // Starting with a configuration of zero, loop through each point in the cube and check if it is below the terrain surface.
    int configurationIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {

        // If it is, use bit-magic to the set the corresponding bit to 1. So if only the 3rd point    in the cube was below
        // the surface, the bit would look like 00100000, which represents the integer value 32.
        if (cube[i] < terrainSurface)
                configurationIndex |= 1 << i;

    }

    return configurationIndex;

}
```

it appears that this is the part that slows my game down, help would be appreciated

i already made it faster by changing terrainpoint from a class to a struct but it is still very slow.

Comment: `it appears that this is the part that slows my game down` .. in general open the profiler window set it to deep profile, run your app => profiler will tell you exactly what is slowing down your app the most, show you allocations and exactly how much performance is used by which methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One main reason it is slow is that there is a **lot of allocations** in the loop putting a **lot of pressure on the garbadge collector**. There is currently 11 allocation per "cube" in the terrain in `_UpdateChunk` and up to 17 in `MarchCube` (possibly even more if the expressions like `position + gamedata.EdgeTable[indice, 0]` allocates a new vector). This is not reasonable. **Many allocation are not needed**. For example `cube` and `strengths` can be preallocated once for all the cubes in the beginning of `_UpdateChunk`. You do not need to allocate the vector in the expression to compute `corner`: you can just compute the components separately manually (or you can possibly preallocate the vector and reset its component when needed). The same thing applies for the `new Vector3(x, y, z)` can can be preallocated and set in the loop. Such an algorithm is computationally intensive so you should get away any overhead like virtual method calls and allocations/GC -- only low-level arrays accesses and mathematical operations should remains.

Note that some computations can be optimized. For example `GetCubeConfiguration` can be modified so to be branchless. `Mathf.Abs(vert1sample)` can be precomputed so not to compute it twice (though the compiler may already do that). I am also wondering if the expression like `vertices.Add` are efficient but this is dependent of the type of container which is not provided here.

Comment: i am now preallocating the cube and strength arrays which made the function a lot faster but you said many allocations were not needed. which?

Comment: Good. Well, for the "which", it is described starting from "For example" to "and set in the loop".